# Redux mapStateToProps property dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### My `mapStateToProps` function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
   object: {},
   criteria: []
 });
```

It contains two properties:

**1. The `object` property**

It get's an object from the store corresponding the URL's object id.

The resulting object looks like this:

```
{
  object: {
    id: 42,
    criteria: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

**2. The `criteria` property**

This one should fetch the criteria objects from the store, with the id's of the previously fetched object's criteria ids.

I came up with the following function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  object: getObjectById(state, props.routeParams.objectId),
  criteria: getCriteriaByIds(state, getObjectById(state, ownProps.routeParams.objectId) ? getObjectById(state, ownProps.routeParams.objectId).criteria : []),
});
```

#### The problem

There is a lot of repetition going on here. If I use `criteria: getCriteriaByIds(state.props.object.criteria)` directly, it seems that the object is equal to the previous state object (and thus the object can be undefined).

I'm sure there must be a simpler way to fetch the criteria without too much repetition in the code.

#### Note

The `getObjectById` and `getCriteriaByIds` are selectors based on the [Colocating selectors with reducers course](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) on Egghead.io.

#### So my question is

> What is the recommended way to work with dependencies on other state
>   properties when working with `mapStateToProps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have anything useful to add about "the recommended way to work with dependencies on other state properties when working with `mapStateToProps`", but I think just adding a local variable will help with the repetition a bit.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  let object = getObjectById(state, props.routeParams.objectId);
  return {
    object,
    criteria: getCriteriaByIds(state, object ? object.criteria : [])
  };
};
```

If you don't expect `object` to be `undefined` this could be further simplified to

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  let object = getObjectById(state, props.routeParams.objectId);
  return {
    object,
    criteria: getCriteriaByIds(state, object.criteria || [])
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to do any kind of selection logic in mapStateToProps. That function is called EVERY time any state is changed, so your logic (`getCriteriaByIds`) will be called a lot.

I suggest to have `objectId` as top level state entry (possible with standalone reducer), so that you can just take it from state object. Consider same for `critetia`.

My suggestion is backed up by [best practices to keep your Redux state as flat (normalized) as possible](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data), even if you will have some repetition there